# Jquery unbinding doesn't work

Tags: jquery, unbind

**First of all** - I have seen *many questions on Stackoverflow related to unbinding using jQuery*, but I didn't find an answer that would solve my specific situation. It's possible that I've missed something - feel free to direct me to the relevant question / answer already posted - thanks!

I have problems with realizing why event/handler unbinding doesn't work.

I'm using Wordpress 4.4 (although I guess Wordpress is irrelevant here), Firefox 42, jQuery 1.11.3.

The relevant parts of my .html and .js files - here's the html part:

```
<div class="py2web-diag-row1-col2">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li> <a class="sol-show" target="<?php echo($id); ?>">Show solution</a> </li>
    <li><a class="sol-hide" target="<?php echo($id); ?>" disabled>Hide solution</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The relevant part from scripts.js file:

```
jQuery(".sol-hide").click(function() {

    // Get id of the corresponding problem solution
    id = this.attributes["target"].value;

    // Show (unhide) solution div element with target attribute of the current problem
    sel = '.p2w-solution[target="' + id + '"]';
    jQuery(sel).css("visibility", "hidden");

    // Deactivate hide-sol and activate show-sol
    sel = '.sol-hide[target="' + id + '"]';
    jQuery(sel).attr("disabled", false);
    this.setAttribute("disabled", true);

    // Activate py2web-s internal events (show moves when clicking on board)
    sel = '.p2w-diagram[id="' + id + '"] .p2w-nav-fwd';
    //jQuery(sel).off("click");
    jQuery(sel).unbind("click");
    sel = '.p2w-diagram[id="' + id + '"] .p2w-nav-bwd';
    //jQuery(sel).off("click");
    jQuery(sel).unbind("click");
});
```

Click event handlers on .p2w-nav-fwd(bwd) elements are defined in another js file, as follows:

```
jQuery(".p2w-nav-fwd").bind("click", Py2Web.navigateForward);
jQuery(".p2w-nav-bwd").bind("click", Py2Web.navigateBackward);
```

and little below, in Py2Web definition:

```
navigateForward: function(L) {
        L.preventDefault();
        C(jQuery('.p2w-solution[target="' + jQuery(this).parent().attr("id") + '"]').children(".active").nextAll("a").first())
    },
navigateBackward: function(L) {
        L.preventDefault();
        C(jQuery('.p2w-solution[target="' + jQuery(this).parent().attr("id") + '"]').children(".active").prevAll("a").first())
    }
```

So, by clicking onto the ".sol-show", i.e. ".sol-hide", anchor, the "click" event handler for .p2w-nav-fwd and .p2w-nav-bwd elements should be enabled (bind), i.e. disabled (unbind). However, unbinding simply doesn't work.

I hope I have provided all the relevant information, please ask for additional if needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the off methode?

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately doesn't work also - I don't know why. There's the same advice in the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem**: in Wordpress, I'm loading my local version of jQuery, not Wordpress' default - but default was loaded *after* local - now I've changed the order of loading, so *all my scripts are loaded only after jQuery* - and it works fine... I should have realized that earlier. Thanks for help and sorry for your time.

Comment: No problema, glad you made it ^^ you should mark your own answer as the right one, after all, you solved it yourself :)

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the selector is working and finding the element?

```
sel = '.p2w-solution[target="' + id + '"]';
```

Also, instead of click and bind i would use "On" and "Off" methods because i've had problems before with "click" and "unbind" and i see that's what you're using.

So, you can use something like this:

```
jQuery(".sol-hide").on('click', function () { 
   sel = '.p2w-solution[target="' + id + '"]';

   ...

   jQuery(sel).off('click');
});
```

I would try that and see what happens.

Comment: I've checked that the selector works as intended. I've also tried 'on' and 'off' methods, doesn't work. There's something wrong here and I don't know what. Where exactly, in js object returned by jQuery selector, can I see all active events and corresponding handlers? Perhaps studying that would help...

Comment: For that i use a chrome extension called Visual Events (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim) hopefully that can help you check the event. Also, did you tried changing this "jQuery(".sol-hide").click" for "jQuery(".sol-hide").on('click', ...)"? i mean, instead of having click+off, have on+off ??

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using only Firefox, not a fan of Chrome. Actually, I have a feedback that unbinding works in Chrome - so it could be some Firefox-related issue - but still I would like to understand it. Regarding your question, "click" event on ".sol-hide" element is not so important here, what I'm interested in is binding / unbinding "click" event on '.p2w-diagram[id="' + id + '"] .p2w-nav-fwd' and '.p2w-diagram[id="' + id + '"] .p2w-nav-bwd' elements, ".sol-hide" is not directly related.